# How to loop over data in JSON?

Tags: python, json

I had a MySQL database stored that way:  Company_name, employee1, employee2, employee3.

When I input a company name, the code look for the company name in my database, then loop over employee1, employee2, and employee3 to check if one of them is free in my calendar.

This was my code to check for the employees :

```
for i in range(3):
    employee = row[i+1]
```

How do I do translate this loop so it can read a JSON structure?

Example of my structure:

```
[
 {
   "id": 1,
   "name_company": "Acier Michel",
   "inspecteur1": "Hou, L",
   "inspecteur2": "Caana, C",
   "inspecteur3": "Luc, C",
   "type": "Water",
   "location": "Laval"
 },
 {
   "id": 2,
   "name_company": "Aciers ABC Inc.",
   "inspecteur1": "Vali, M",
   "inspecteur2": "Alemane, K",
   "inspecteur3": "laszik, M",
   "type": "NA",
   "location": "St-Joseph de Sorel"
 }
]
```

I want to be able to iterate through inspecteur1, inspecteur2 and inspecteur 3.

Comment: Could you elaborate your final question?  What do you mean by "translate this for my JSON file"?  That is, what are you trying to do?

Comment: What json file? Can you give some more details about the structure of the json and its use?

Comment: I updated my question @TenaciousB Also, the use of the file is : When the user input a company, it checks for the `name_company ` and it's respective inspecteur1, inspecteur2 and inspecteur3. The goal is to see who's free between these 3, by order, in my google calendar API. I havnt provided this part of the code because i didnt think it was necessary..

Answer (score 1):

First translate the json to python object with

```
import json
userList = json.loads(yourJsonString)
```

Then iterate on the list

```
for user in userList:
    print(user)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but what I would like to know, is how do i iterate for 3 the inspectors. If you look at my question, there's a company named "Acier Michel". If I search for it, I want my code to loop over these 3 inspectors (inspecteur1, inspecteur2, inspecteur3) assigned to Acier Michel

Answer (score 0):

### The data is a list of dictionaries

- Use `pandas`
- This assumes your list of dictionaries is in a file

```py
import pandas as pd
import json
from pathlib import Path

# path to file
p = Path(r'c:\path_to_file\test.json')

# read the file
with p.open('r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    data = json.loads(f.read())

# load into pandas
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df)

 id     name_company inspecteur1 inspecteur2 inspecteur3   type            location
  1     Acier Michel      Hou, L    Caana, C      Luc, C  Water               Laval
  2  Aciers ABC Inc.     Vali, M  Alemane, K   laszik, M     NA  St-Joseph de Sorel

# search datafram
search = df[['inspecteur1', 'inspecteur2', 'inspecteur3']][df.name_company == 'Aciers ABC Inc.']

print(search)

inspecteur1 inspecteur2 inspecteur3
    Vali, M  Alemane, K   laszik, M
```

### Note addressing comment:

- With `search` you have access to the desired values of `inspecteur1-3`
- `search.values` returns an numpy array, which can be iterated through.
- There is not enough information in the question to offer a more comprehensive solution.

```py
for name in search.values[0]:
     print(name)

Vali, M
Alemane, K
laszik, M
```

- Additionally, the dataframe can be updated with additional columns and or rows and saved back in to a file.

  - `df.to_json('test.json', orient='records')`